# How to Style a Bootstrap 5 `navbar-brand` Icon and Link with the Same Color

Tags: bootstrap-5

I'm having a problem styling a Bootstrap `navbar-brand`.

I've tried multiple different techniques in order to style a Bootstrap 5 `navbar-brand` icon and link with the same color. I've tried changing class names on the `<a>` tag, the `<svg>` tag, the `<path>` tag, and the `<span>` tag. I've tried wrapping the icon and link in a `<div>` and adding a class there but that didn't work, either. I'm currently using the `<svg>` given by Bootstrap icons but I've even tried using an external `<svg>` in a separate folder but that didn't work. I'm trying to make the icon and link a uniform `#e1b10f;` color but wherever I try to add the color style, it doesn't work. The only thing which has worked is adding `fill: currentColor` to the `<svg>` and adding the color style to the `<span class="navbar-title">`, which the `<svg>` then picks up by association. But this definitely won't work when I want to add further styles such as `a:hover`, or `a:visited`, etc.
Here is the code for the `navbar-brand`:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark dark fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid px-5 py-2">
    <div class="col-2 col-md-4">
      <a class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
        <svg 
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
          width="20" 
          height="20" 
          fill="currentColor"
          class="bi bi-vinyl-fill me-2" 
          viewBox="0 0 16 16"
        >
          <path d="M8 6a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm0 3a1 1 0 1 1 0-2 1 1 0 0 1 0 2z"/>
          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zM4 8a4 4 0 1 0 8 0 4 4 0 0 0-8 0z"/>
        </svg>
        <span class="navbar-title">Record Review</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: just add a [`.text-*`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/colors/#colors) color class to the link, e.g.: `<a class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center text-danger" href="#">`

Comment: OK, that works (using `text-warning`). But what if I want to change the color when the `navbar-brand` is mouse-clicked, etc.?

Comment: that's not part of bootstrap, so you'd have to use manual css, e.g. `.navbar-brand:visited {color: yellow !important}`